# How to display a tooltip in Dynamics AX 4.0?

Tags: x++, axapta

I'm looking to add hover text to a given column in a grid with row specific data. I'm planning on overriding the mouse-enter event, but I'm unsure how to populate a Tooltip and have it display next to the mouse.

Any direction would be appreciated, thanks!

**Edit: It looks like the method to override is actually called "Tooltip". I was able to override this and get a tooltip to display.

The question remains: How to access the current row's data for the column that the Tooltip is on?

Comment: This is a very unusual request. What are you trying to achieve in the first place? Try to be high level!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a tooltip with the description of the foreign key field, the following must be met:

1. Base your field on an extended data type
2. Put a relation on the extended data type
3. Have the relation point to a base table
4. Set the `TitleField1` and `TitleField2` attributes on the base table
5. Have a unique index on the key fields of your base table

You can put the relation on the (transaction) table instead of the extended data type.
Do that in AX 2012 or if the relation has more than one field to join.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the tooltip code that I ended up using:

```
public str toolTip()
{
    ;
    return tblYourTable::find(this.value()).Description;
}
```

**Edit per Jan's comment to greatly simplify code

Comment: This certainly works and is plenty fast for my application. Why is this the wrong way to do it?

Comment: It can be achieved without code, see the my answer. Code style: it should be a oneliner: 
return tblYourTable::find(this.value()).Description;

Comment: I agree with your comment and have marked your response as the correct answer. I'll leave this code here as it is usable and might be more applicable in certain situations.